# Regex simple split

Tags: regex, split

I have this sentence:

```
Objet[id=100,name=car,type=grey,source=sourceId{id=12,version=12},linked=true]
```

I would like to isolate the result of the equality. Which give me something like that:

```
100
car
grey
sourceId{id=12,version=12}
true
```

As you can see the difficulty is because of the field source, which contain also equality but I don't want to split them. (Otherwise I would use `\w*(=)`.)

Comment: What language? Please tag accordingly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Learning Regular Expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 0):

Regex: **`/\w+=(\w+\{.*?\})|\w+=(\w+)/g`**

Solution for above requirement can be done easily in Perl one liner:

```
perl -le '$str = "Objet[id=100,name=car,type=grey,source=sourceId{id=12,version=12},linked=true]"; print "$2$1 " while ($str =~ /\w+=(\w+\{.*?\})|\w+=(\w+)/g);'
```

In Javascript, check here: https://regex101.com/r/wD0dL9/1.
You can print group2 and group1 for desired result.

Comment: Thanks, could you give me a regex  which only match the sing '=' (but not the equal in the field sourceId!) ?

Comment: Will string pattern remain always same? I mean, amongst `key=value`, will `key` be always same?
i.e. Is this your string? `Objet[id=XXX,name=XXX,type=XXX,source=XXX{id=XXX,version=XXX},linked=XXX]` where XXX is a varible.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var regexp = /[a-zA-Z]+=(\w+{*(?:[a-zA-Z]+=*[\w=,]*)?}*),*/g;
```

demo : https://regex101.com/r/mM3dP2/3

MATCH 1:    `100`

MATCH 2:    `car`

MATCH 3:    `grey`

MATCH 4:    `sourceId{id=12,version=12}`

MATCH 5:    `true`

Comment: Thanks, could you give me a regex  which only match the sing '=' (but not the equal in the field sourceId!) ?